# Terminal(kitty) colors altering vim color scheme

Tags: vim, colors, kitty

I'm using the base16 color schemes for both my terminal(kitty) and vim. However changing the color scheme of kitty results in the color scheme of vim changing into something similar.

The relevant(I'm guessing) part of my `.vimrc` looks like this:

```
set background=dark
let base16colorspace=256
colorscheme base16-default-dark
syntax enable
```

Despite the setting of colorscheme, vim adopts kitty's scheme...
I'd like separate schemes for the two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `kovidgoyal` says:

> Add the following to your .vimrc

```
    " vim hardcodes background color erase even if the terminfo file does
    " not contain bce (not to mention that libvte based terminals
    " incorrectly contain bce in their terminfo files). This causes
    " incorrect background rendering when using a color theme with a
    " background color.
    let &t_ut=''
```

source- https://github.com/kovidgoyal/kitty/issues/108#issuecomment-320492663

Hope it helps!